# Image upload security - reprocess with GD

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, gd

I've heard that the best way to handle uploaded images is to "re-process" them using the `GD`  library and save the processed image. see: [PHP image upload security check list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166762/php-image-upload-security-check-list)

My question is how do this "re-processing" in `GD`? What this means exactly? I don't know the GD library very well and I'm afraid I will mess it up...

So if anyone who did this before could you give me an example for this?

(I know, another other option is to use ImageMagick. For ImageMagick I found an answer here: [Remove EXIF data from JPG using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614925/remove-exif-data-from-jpg-using-php),  but I can't use ImgMagick now. By the way.. removing EXIF data means completely recreate the image in this case?)
(I'm using Zend Framework if someone interested.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user uploads a JPEG file, you could do something like this to reprocess it:

```
$newIm = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if (!$newIm) {
    // gd could not create an image from the source
    // most likely, the file was not a valid jpeg image
}
```

You could then discard the `$newIm` image using [imagedestroy()](http://php.net/imagedestroy) and use the uploaded file from the user, or save out the image from GD and use that.  There could be some issues with saving the GD image as it is not the original image.

Another simple method would be to check the header (first several bytes) of the image file to make sure it is correct; for example all JPEG files begin with `0xff 0xd8`.

See also [imagecreatefromstring()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php), and you can also use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/getimagesize) to run similar checks on the uploaded image.

Comment: Quote (getimagesize) "Caution
This function expects filename to be a valid image file. If a non-image file is supplied, it may be incorrectly detected as an image and the function will return successfully, but the array may contain nonsensical values.
Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead."

Answer (score 3):

```
function isvalidjpeg($file) 
{ 
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
return is_resource($finfo) && 
       (finfo_file($finfo, $file) === 'image/jpeg') && 
       finfo_close($finfo);
}
if(isvalidjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
   $newIm = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); .....
```