# How delete exif data in this function?

Tags: php, netbeans

I don't know how delete `exif` data from uploaded pictures. Here is my function:

```
$uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();

if ($uploadedFiles && $id) {
    $usersPath = '/collections/' . date('Y/m') . '/' . $id .'/';
    $uploadFolder = realpath(BASE_PATH . '/uploads');
    $uploadFolder .= $usersPath;
    $newName = md5(time() . serialize($uploadedFiles));

    $fileExtension = strtolower($uploadedFiles[0]->getExtension());
    $sourceImgPath = $uploadFolder .$newName .'.' .$fileExtension;

    if (!file_exists($uploadFolder)) {
        mkdir($uploadFolder, 0777, true );
    }

    if(in_array($fileExtension, array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'))){

        if ($uploadedFiles[0]->moveTo($sourceImgPath)) {
            $info = pathinfo($sourceImgPath);

            if ($info) {
                $file_path = $usersPath . $info['filename'] . '.' . $fileExtension;
                (new \Rapid\Storage\CollectionsStorage())->editImage($id, $file_path);
            } else {
                $session->set('msg_error', $this->translate->_('There was an unexpected error with uploading the file'));
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    $session->set('msg_error', $this->translate->_('Invalid file type'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should delete all EXIF information in JPEG

```
$img = new Imagick($uploadfile);
$img->stripImage();
$img->writeImage($uploadfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the graphics libraries you have access to.

- If you have access to imagick, you can use [`stripImage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.stripimage.php).
- If you have only access to gd, you need to create a new image from the upload and save that instead, see for example [PHP remove exif data from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812383/php-remove-exif-data-from-images) for a jpg image.

Comment: I was try to delete like this:

Comment: $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImgPath);
                        imagejpeg ($img, $sourceImgPath, 100);
                        imagedestroy ($img);

Comment: $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImgPath);
                        imagejpeg ($img, $sourceImgPath, 100);
                        imagedestroy ($img);

Comment: sorry two time copy

Comment: @ScottEvans You need to add error handling, all calls to gd functions return values that will tell you if they succeeded.

Comment: maybe you know how to make all jpeg images : OrientationHorizontal (normal)