# How to Remove EXIF (image file) data in PHP?

Tags: php, exif

**I have installed imagick library and checked using this command: 
`php -m | grep imagick`. It is working.
but when I  referred to the same reference,it is giving me blank array.**

Here is my code:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $incoming_file = '/var/www/html/demos/exif/tim.jpg';
    $img = new Imagick(realpath($incoming_file));
    $profiles = $img->getImageProfiles("icc", true);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($profiles);
```

When I try to print `$profiles` nothing is returned. It gives me an empty array.

[Reference Link for exif data in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614925/remove-exif-data-from-jpg-using-php)

Comment: All images simply don't have icc-profiles embedded into them. If you get an empty response, just skip that step.

Comment: Yet I didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

This will show you EXIF information from JPEG file in PHP. Try use relative path and check if script can read from this directory (permissions).

```
$uploadfile = "uploaded/pic.jpg";
$exif = exif_read_data($uploadfile, 0, true);
echo "<b>Your file</b><br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
```

And this piece of code should delete all EXIF information

```
$img = new Imagick($uploadfile);
$img->stripImage();
$img->writeImage($uploadfile);
```

You can try it here:
https://iconnaut.com/exif.php