# remove Exiff from UploadedFile Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have form that use to upload picture.
I can't save this picture on my server, But I send it to another service ( external)

I have to encode base 64

my code is:

```
$base_img = base64_encode(file_get_contents($data["image"]));
```

where $data['image'] is UploadedFile

How can Remove all Exiff from $data['image'] before encode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove EXIF data from JPG using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614925/remove-exif-data-from-jpg-using-php)

Comment: it's not a possible duplicate, i CAN'T save on my server

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php

Comment: I have to remove exiff and then convert to base64

Comment: soooo import the file data into imagemagic and export it and convert that to base64?

Comment: I try with $imagick = new \Imagick($data["image"]->getRealPath()); but $imagick in empty

Answer (score 0):

Recently I needed exactly that and I achieved it with passing `$uploadedFile->getRealPath()` to the Imagick. Complete function:

```
/**
 * @param UploadedFile $uploadedFile
 * @throws \ImagickException
 */
public function stripMeta(UploadedFile $uploadedFile): void
{
    $img = new Imagick($uploadedFile->getRealPath());
    $profiles = $img->getImageProfiles("icc", true);
    $img->stripImage();
    if(!empty($profiles)) {
        $img->profileImage("icc", $profiles['icc']);
    }
    $img->writeImage($uploadedFile->getRealPath());
}
```

I took saving icc profile idea from comments here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.stripimage.php