# PHP Imagick returns a corrupted image after conversion to png extension

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

I have a PHP script, which works well in 99% of all cases. It converts images from any extension to the png extension.

But on some images, Imagick returns a broken image, although the source is valid. I have tried it with two different Imagick versions. I can convert the image to every other extension without problems, its just the png extension that makes trouble.

This is my current test script:

```
<?php

$picture = file_get_contents('https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/51074989067_cb57612f5f_o.jpg');

$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($picture);

$output1=$image->getImageBlob();
$image->setImageFormat("png");
$output2=$image->getImageBlob();

file_put_contents("image_is_valid.jpg", $output1);
file_put_contents("image_is_corrupted.png", $output2);    

?>
```

Could someone please give me hint, what exactly is damaging the image?

Just to clarify: Both images seems to be valid, but if you open them with GIMP, only the jpg file is working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: image is big and site has rate limiting, took over 30 secs to load, enable error reporting and check error logs, load up the image in a hex editor, try a smaller image etc

Comment: Also be sure you have the latest libpng installed with ImageMagick.

Comment: The JPG appears to be have some underlying data that is not compatible with PNG when opened in GIMP, despite still being viewed in other image processors.  See [Remove EXIF data from JPG using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615080/1144627) Size is reduced to ~4 MB from 25 MB uncompressed. But calling `Imagick::stripImage()` resolves the issue of it being reported as corrupted. in GIMP. Tested with GD `imagepng(imagecreatefromjpeg(), ...)` and got similar results.

Comment: @WillB. That has solved my problem! Thanks for your help! If you post it as answer, I would mark it as correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove EXIF data from JPG using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614925/remove-exif-data-from-jpg-using-php)